# repeated-measures ANOVA

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

By calculating a repeated-measures ANOVA, no partial eta squared is listed in the table and I can't calculate any post-hoc tests.

Does anybody know possible reasons for this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What software are you using? What function?

Comment: @user2974951 I'm using SPSS (v. 24)